# Why do the <img> tags do not get replaced by the preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex

I want to entirely remove the img tag elements from the string $str. Here goes my code:

```
<?php

$re = '@<img[^>]*?/>@siu'; 
$str = '<div style="position:absolute;top:10.26in;left:6.9193in;width:0.107409in;line-height:0.151711in;"><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:8pt;font-family:Avenir LT Std 55 Roman;color:#000000">1</span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:8pt;font-family:Avenir LT Std 55 Roman;color:#000000"> </span><br/></SPAN></div>
<img style="position:absolute;top:0.880967in;left:6.85455in;width:1.09091in;height:0.363637in" src="ri_1.png" />
<img style="position:absolute;top:0.879515in;left:0.445455in;width:6.72727in;height:0.363636in" src="ci_1.png" />
<div style="position:absolute;top:0.868212in;left:0.718182in;width:2.06073in;line-height:0.333273in;"><span style="font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;font-family:Myriad Pro Light;color:#000000">Abi</span><span style="font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;font-family:Myriad Pro Light;color:#000000">es</span><span style="font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;font-family:Myriad Pro Light;color:#000000"> </span></SPAN><br/></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:0.868212in;left:0.718182in;width:2.06073in;line-height:0.333273in;"><DIV style="position:relative; left:0.662291in;"><span style="font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;font-family:Myriad Pro Light;color:#000000">we</span><span style="font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;font-family:Myriad Pro Light;color:#000000">b</span><span style="font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;font-family:Myriad Pro Light;color:#000000">bi</span><span style="font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;font-family:Myriad Pro Light;color:#000000">an</span><span style="font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;font-family:Myriad Pro Light;color:#000000">a</span><span style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;font-family:Myriad Pro Light;color:#000000"> </span><br/></SPAN></DIV></div>';

$rep="//";

mb_regex_encoding("UTF-8");
mb_ereg_replace($re, $rep, $str);

echo $str;

?>
```

The same regex and string when used with `preg_match-all()` returns all the correct matches.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img style="position:absolute;top:0.880967in;left:6.85455in;width:1.09091in;height:0.363637in" src="ri_1.png" />
            [1] => <img style="position:absolute;top:0.879515in;left:0.445455in;width:6.72727in;height:0.363636in" src="ci_1.png" />
    )

)
```

If the matches are made, why not the replacements? Please suggest a way to remove the img tags.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code. Check out the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) for `mb_ereg_replace`, particularly the fourth parameter and the return value.

The first problem is that you're including flags in your regex, where `mb_ereg_replace` doesn't accept flags in its regex string. You have to provide those via the fourth parameter (and it only accepts `ixmpe`).

The second problem is that you're expecting `mb_ereg_replace` to mutate its arguments, where most functions don't do that. Instead, they return the value you're expecting. All you have to do is store the result of the function in a variable.

(Also, as I said, `mb_ereg_replace` doesn't work with the `s` or `u` flags, check the documentation.)

So:

```
$re = '<img[^>]*?/>'; 

$newStr = mb_ereg_replace($re, $rep, $str, 'i');

echo $newStr;
```

**Edit**: I looked into this some more, and I may have been wrong about which flags `mb_ereg_replace` accepts. But your regex would work with or without the `s` and `u` flags.